# Is it possible to mirror an Android device’s screen to a Surface Pro?

Tags: android, mirroring, microsoft-surface

I have a Galaxy S5 and I’d like to mirror my screen to a Surface Pro. I have Chromecast but so far I’ve been unable to get my Galaxy S5 to recognize the Surface Pro as a device.

Is there a better way to mirror my Galaxy S5 screen to the Surface Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an app called [SideSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.sidesync30&hl=en) that does exactly what I was looking for. After installing it on my phone and my surface I'm able to mirror my phone to the surface.

Comment: The link seems dead.